# How to actually notate figured bass in Musixtex?

Tags: musixtex

|Preferably with a short example. Thanks!

Edit: here is my own short example. I simply want to add a 6 underneath the first and third chords, as per standard figured bass notation.

```
\begin{music}
\nobarnumbers
\instrumentnumber{1} 
\setstaffs{1}{2}
\setclef1\bass
\startextract
\NOTEs\rw{'CG'}|\rw{e'e}\en
\bar
\NOTEs\rw{'F'A}|\rw{f'c}\en
\doublebar
\NOTEs\rw{'G'B}|\rw{g'e}\en
\bar
\NOTEs\rw{'CJ}|\rw{g'e}\en
\setdoublebar
\endextract
\end{music}
```

Comment: Could you provide a small document yourself with a few bars of music in Musixtex notation in it where you want to add figured bass markings, and make a mock-up picture in an image editor (or a clear description in your question) of which symbols you want to add and where? That would make it much easier to address your question, and it would also make sure, if solutions are given, that these solutions actually correspond to what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text commands for this, there is an example in the [current manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/musixtex/doc/musixdoc.pdf) on page 75 at the bottom.

The command `\zchar{position}{text}` allows you to place the `text` at the given vertical `position`. The position is counted from the lowest staff line, below the staff is approximately `-4`. To get a nice number you can use the time signature font, either `\metersmallfont` or `\meternorfont` (a bit bigger).

Now, because you use shifted whole notes (with `\rw`) you need to shift the number a bit as well. In the definition of `\rw` you can find that the shift is performed with the `\kern` command and the amount of shift is equal to `\wn@width`, so the width of a whole note, by default `7.5pt`.

So, in order to put a figure bass number below a note, you can use something like `\zchar{-4}{\kern 7.5pt\metersmallfont 6}`. Because this is a bit long to type, you can define a macro with arguments for the vertical position and the number. In the MWE below I defined two macros, one with the small font, one with the normal font.

If you need two numbers then you can use `\meterfrac` as argument. However, because `\meterfrac` sets a big meterfont internally, you should specify that the font is small for each number.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\makeatletter
\def\figshift{\kern \wn@width}
\newcommand{\smallfigurebass}[2]{%
\zchar{#1}{\figshift\metersmallfont #2}%
}
\newcommand{\normalfigurebass}[2]{%
\zchar{#1}{\figshift\meternorfont #2}%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\nobarnumbers
\instrumentnumber{1} 
\setstaffs{1}{2}
\setclef1\bass
\startextract
\NOTEs\zchar{-4}{\kern 7.5pt\metersmallfont 6}\rw{'CG'}|\rw{e'e}\en
\bar
\NOTEs\smallfigurebass{-4}{6}\rw{'F'A}|\rw{f'c}\en
\doublebar
\NOTEs\normalfigurebass{-4}{6}\rw{'G'B}|\rw{g'e}\en
\bar
\NOTEs\smallfigurebass{-8}{\meterfrac{\metersmallfont 4}{\metersmallfont 6}}\rw{'CJ}|\rw{g'e}\en
\setdoublebar
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]